# In python 2.7 can you make the __contains__ super method take 3 arguments?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am wanting to make the super method **contains** work a little differently.

I want to make it so that you can give it a two integers. And if the first integer is less than the instance of the class, and the second integer is greater than the instance of the class It will return True. This is my attempt.

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item= item
    def __contains__(self,other1,other2):
        if other1<self.item<other2:
            return True
        else:
            return False

x=test(5)

print 1 in x
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: __contains__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

As you can see I don't even know how I would do 3 arguments for the **contains** method. But for the sake of example, Id try just checking if 5 is in between 1 and 7.

I know I can do this in a method I can make myself, but I'm wanting to work with the **in** keyword.

Comment: Those aren't called "super methods". The usual terms are "magic method" or "special method".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want some sort of 3-argument `in` operator, you'd have to build your own deeply modified Python interpreter, including rewriting the fundamental syntax rules.

You could take a tuple easily enough, though:

```
class Blah(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __contains__(self, l):
        a, b = l
        return a < self.val < b

print (1, 3) in Blah(2)
```

It doesn't make much sense, but it's doable.